# Ubuntu supported file systems and cross OS linking

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem, ntfs, 20.04

1) How well does Ubuntu support NTFS?
2) I want to make Ubuntu save all my Documents, Videos, Music, etc... in my /home to the same location that windows 10 saves the. I mean everything except the desktop files. Is it possible to create such a link? **Note: I don't save my files using windows in the C: partition. I use a separate D: partition for that. I want to link Ubuntu created file to that D: partition**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ntfs3g is from Microsoft partner Tuxera.  If you ask Microsoft for ntfs/exfat license on Linux, Microsoft will tell you to find Tuxera(or Paragon, of course). NTFS is now considered fully working except that ntfs3g does not have journaling feature and slower due to its fuse-based nature
2. There's nothing prevent you use symbolic link 'to' other filesystems.  You don't need any special software support.

   However I suggest against creating symbolic link 'on' ntfs drive, since Windows will see them as file system errors.

   You will also need to check ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs points to correct locations, because Gnome sometimes points those folders to $HOME as fallback if you remove the default folders.  After create symbolic links, you might want to change them back.

Comment: So can you tell me how to create the link? In windows, I just changed the location of 3D Objects, Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Video folders. How do I do this in Ubuntu 20.04? Just to clarify, I do not wish to make a link to the Windows home partition (C: partition).